# Delete from a table where the geometry intersects the geometry of another table?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql

Is there a way to delete data in one table that intersects the geomety of another table? I am using PostGIS.

Effectively I would like to do the following, but this returns an error.

```
DELETE FROM table_A
WHERE st_intersects(table_A.geom, table_B.geom)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to reference the second table with `USING`:

```
DELETE FROM table_A AS a
USING table_B AS b
WHERE ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom);
```

See the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/sql-delete.html) under 'Notes' for details.

Comment: Nice and straightforward and it works perfectly, thank you!

Comment: @ste_j happy to help. care to accept? (wait for 24h according to the boards recommendations, but...)

Comment: @ste_j ;) cheers